# Is my lecturer correct or incorrect about Association Classes?

Tags: associations, uml, class-diagram

Here are their lecture slides concerning association classes:

> Sometimes associations have attributes or behavior that does not
>   belong solely to the class at either end. We can model this using an
>   association class. Assume the following diagram models the allocation
>   of students to modules.
>
> [image]
>
> The attribute `finalMark` does not ‘fit’ into either ‘end’ of the
>   association. In addition, it will be necessary to record more than one
>   mark for each student (for each module) and vice versa. Thus, the
>   attribute `finalMark` is an attribute of the association between
>   `Student` and `Module`.
>
> [image]
>
> The association class adds an extra constraint in that there can only
>   be one instance of the association class between any two participating
>   objects. Therefore, if we allowed `students` to re-sit modules but we
>   still needed to retain the `finalMark`’s of previous `enrolment`s, we
>   could not use an association class and would need to ‘add’ a class,
>   Enrolment, and two more associations.
>
> [image]
>
> Also a `Customer` and `Performance` example. It needs to be a full class as customer can have many bookings:
>
> [image]

I'm really struggling to agree with changing dotted notation into the full class. I have looked all over the internet about this and cannot not find anything that uses this approach. I have found the article in which my lecturer got their information from ([here](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Association+Class/)) but even the comment on that articles challenges its correctness.

It's really giving me a headache when attempting their assignment they have set so I would like some clarity on the issue.

Comment: The picture #3 shows another rendering of #2 where the `Enrolled on` is actually not needed and just added for readability. Association classes bind two (or more) classes and add functionality. Technically an association class is a mix of an association and a class.

Comment: As a side note: it's not a dotted but a dashed line for association classes.

Comment: See also p. 205 of the UML specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint they are refering is not existant, for association classes, even when isUnique is set to true. For usual associations, you need to set isUnique to false, to allow this.

A reason why you have found that much information about such a transforming is that many people don't use association classes and instead define immediately with such a "full" class to realize the association. Besides of the fact that the two classes have no direct association, there is technically no real difference between these two concepts. This means in a realization you cannot distinguish in general if the class that realizes the association was defined as an association class or just as a class. Because an association class is also a "full" class (if you want to call it like that), because it is related to the term class by a generalization relation, such as to an association. In consequece it inherits the properties of both (huh, meta-model).
To overcome the missing direct association and the not existing constraint, they presented one possible solution. But before discussing them, we can ask if we realy need those both properties? So we need to have the relation several times logically, as defined in the problem: yes. Do we need an direct association between the two instances? Hmm... here, not really. In some cases there might some reasons for this, e.g., when a high level architecture is defined and you are only allowed to refine and complete it, but cannot remove an association, which was defined on a higher level, another reason could be some tool issues or when you want to process the model automatically, or you depending on used database engines, the resolution of associated objects might be faster. But basically you have the connection between the instances without the association.

Another solution would be having the association class and having a further class that contains the information that can be added over time and still contributes to this association. So the class that adds the information can only be linked to one instance of the association class, and the association class can link to arbitrary (or whatever the rules are) instances.

[image]

Using qualifiers is, theoretically, also a possibility but I would recommend not to use it for this case, because its intension is somewhat different.

But as always, each approach has some benefits and drawbacks. And for an exam it is mostly better to conform with the teachers, as long as they are not wrong :-)

Comment: You should make a correction regarding your first statement. See Geert's answer. Else your answer is fine.

Comment: Just corrected it and gave a further example on why an association class can beuseful in some situations.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with your lecturer.
In fact the UML specification explicitly states the opposite

UML v 2.5 Page 199

> NOTE. Even when all ends of the AssociationClass have isUnique=true,
>   it is possible to have several instances associating the same set of
>   instances of the end Classes.

I don't think changing the association into an association class changes anything to the constraints already imposed by the association.

The example association has a `[1..*]` multiplicity on both ends. That means that every instance of a `Student` has to be enrolled in one or **more** `Module`, but it doesn't say that a student cannot be enrolled in the same module more then once.

Making the association an association class doesn't suddenly change that, so the "solution", changing the association class into two associations linked to a enrollment class doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Well spotted, Geert!

Comment: Yea, this is what I was afraid of but I'll just have to go with their thinking as they're the one marking the assignment :)

Comment: @user1323 as said in my answer,I would not going conform when they are wrong. Here you have the UML standard to proof your solution. Maybe this changed compared to some older UML version, and they are not aware of this.

Comment: I disagree with one statement above: The diagram _does_ say that a student cannot be enrolled in the same module more than once. The default value for `isUnique` is true, and therefore each module can only be once in the collection of modules linked to the student. That doesn't say anything about the number of links. Links and the sets at the end of links are different concepts, as strange as this may sound.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version of the UML your lecturer is teaching you. In version 1 they’re correct, in version 2 they’re not.

Also I think your lecturer is possibly trying to teach you something about the analysis and design process here. There are many ways to represent things in UML as it is a general purpose language (like many we use in IT); what they may be trying to show you is how to think through problems and evolve your model as you discover more information and answer questions. This is very much modelling in the real world — constant reiteration as you elaborate, readjustments and a gradual settling on a representation that best communicates to you and your stakeholders, whomever they may be and whatever their desires and needs are. You definitely need to know about the technicalities but you also need to know about when it is good enough and to get on with the job. In other words — they may be wrong, depending on the context (which I can’t comment on more) but in reality it doesn’t matter that much.

Answer (score 0):

Technically these notation are slightly different, however in practice you are not able to code the association class.
While building requirements and designing the application at the business level you should stay with the association class (it's there for a reason! It is also more readable).
Yet, when going into the technical design that has to take code limitation into consideration you should replace association classes with alternative representation like you were shown in the class.

Here's another example (sorry, I don't know how well will it lead, in case it's needed, check pages 259 and 260)

https://books.google.pl/books?id=v7JL2oKwFEAC&pg=PA258&lpg=PA258&dq=replacing+association+class+with+class&source=bl&ots=VXiMY2efu3&sig=D4rXwBf8fQQsMhaF2EaWlF_NJcQ&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv89X0seLYAhVSb5oKHXjVDog4ChDoAQhcMAc#v=onepage&q=replacing%20association%20class%20with%20class&f=false

It's not exact example as there is no derived association, but you see the same approach in terms of adding the class representing association with two associations leading one to each associated class. Additional derived association directly shows that this is actually representation of association between the two.

Comment: Not all class diagrams are meant to be translated into code. There are a lot of other uses.

Comment: You're quite right @GeertBellekens , I'll correct my answer to indicate that this change is needed when going on the technical design level.